# I cannot pod install

Tags: macos, cocoapods

I cannot pod install.
This is error.
I want u help me.

```
 xcrun: error: SDK "iphoneos" cannot be located
    xcrun: error: SDK "iphoneos" cannot be located
    xcrun: error: SDK "iphoneos" cannot be located
    xcrun: error: unable to lookup item 'Path' in SDK 'iphoneos'
    /Users/dan/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/Release/Flipper-Glog/0.3.6-1dfd6/missing: Unknown `--is-lightweight' option
    Try `/Users/dan/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/Release/Flipper-Glog/0.3.6-1dfd6/missing --help' for more information
    configure: WARNING: 'missing' script is too old or missing
    configure: error: in `/Users/dan/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/Release/Flipper-Glog/0.3.6-1dfd6':
    configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
    See `config.log' for more details
```

Answer (score 15):

Proceed to Xcode > Preferences > Locations.

Check if Command Line Tool is selected and not blank.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Thats errors indicates that C compiler it not working.

Please make sure you have proper Xcode when setting up a new machine, and here fixed iPhone sdk issue.

run this

> sudo xcode-select --print-path

If XCode is installed, you should see a wrong installation path, such as /Library/Developer/ or something like that: it’s very likely that your XCode installation is located somewhere else – such as in the /Applications/ folder. If that’s so, you can fix your issue by typing the following command:

> sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app

Thanks to this:

[Click for detail](https://www.ryadel.com/en/xcode-sdk-iphoneos-cannot-be-located-mac-osx-error-fix/)

Answer (score 0):

If the other solutions didnt work yet.

Try the following in the main project folder

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

Then,

```
cd ios
pod install
```

It worked for me